# jQuery media queries for toggle button - different action depending on screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mmenu, matchmedia

I have a toggle button which basically shows/hides a list of filters on a Product Index page. Desktop is simple, when clicking the button the panel is shown or hidden with the following script:

```
$(".filter-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".grid").toggleClass("hide-filters");
});
```

When the browser is below 1024px I use the mmenu plugin to duplicate the filters content and move it into an off-canvas panel. The code for that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".filters").mmenu({
        // Options
        navbar: {
            title: "Filters"
        }
    }, {
        // Configuration
        clone: true,
        offCanvas: {
            pageSelector: ".page"
        },
        classNames: {
            selected: "active"
        }
    });

    var API = $(".filters").data("mmenu");
    var $icon = $(".filter-toggle");

    $icon.on("click", function() {
        API.open();
    });
});
```

Obviously (at the minute) when the toggle button is clicked it will show/hide the content on the page but also trigger the slide-out menu at the same time.

My question is how can I only run the relevant script when it's needed. Is it also possible to do this on resize on not just on pageLoad/refresh?

I tried using `matchMedia`. Here's a quick CodePen showing where I'm at...

https://codepen.io/moy/pen/wymvjN

It looked like it worked to begin with. Above 1024px the toggle worked. Shrinking the browser down meant the button triggered the slide-out panel - great! But when scaling back up to desktop the slide-out menu is triggered whenever the toggle is clicked. On refresh it works again ...until you shrink the browser down and back up again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for window resize events, and fire functions accordingly. For example, in jQuery:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

  if (windowWidth < 1024) {
    // initialize small viewport functionality
  } else {
    // initialized large viewport functionality
  }
});
```

But, you'll need a way to disable that `mmenu` plugin when switching back to desktop, and include it in whatever script you run during that condition.

Alternatively, [the mmenu "Responsive Layout" documentation](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/support/tips-and-tricks.html) provides an example for using CSS media queries to hide the cloned menu at certain breakpoints.

Comment: Ah i guess that explains why it stops working on resize but is ok on load Once the mmenu script has been triggered it’s difficult to get rid of. Ok i’ll Just `Display: none;` the menu. Would you advise using a query to stop the function of the toggle of the desktop menu? Or just hide that with CSS as well? Wondering if having 2 buttons would also be an option.

Comment: You could certainly have two separate buttons with different functionalities and then toggle their CSS `display` using media queries. Given the limitations of this particular library, it might be your best option, even though it comes with some maintenance.

Alternatively: ditch that library entirely. Have a single button that toggles a class on the menu system, like `.menu-toggled`. Then use CSS media queries to determine how that toggle class displays the content. On desktop, it simply shows/hides the display. On mobile, it changes the left position.

Comment: I'm already using the plugin for a nested menu in the header so I suppose it might be worth keeping so it works/looks the same and no extra code is loaded as the script is already running. But if that wasn't the case it maybe is a bit OTT and writing some custom css would be better. Do you think 2 buttons would be better, so both scripts aren't essentially triggered at the same time?